# Mysql Inner Join tables that inherit same table

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have the following database schema. The tables VHS and DVD both inherit from Suport_Media and both contain one Film (Film translated in english means movie). I want to create a view that contains the informations about all available Suport_Media with the movies they contain. To do this, I have to combine the tables suport_media, dvd, vhs and film into one table with inner joins. The problem is that I can't figure out how to combine VHS and DVD into one table and then join it with Suport_Media and Film.

I have tried the following code:

```
CREATE
VIEW Informatii_Suport_Media AS
SELECT Titlu, Actori_Principali, Tip, Durata_Film, Data_Lansare, Pret
FROM VHS V
INNER JOIN DVD D ON V.Suport_Media_ID <> D.Suport_Media_ID
INNER JOIN DVD D1 ON Suport_Media.Suport_Media_ID = D.Suport_Media_ID
INNER JOIN Film F ON F.Film_ID = D1.Film_ID
GROUP BY V.Suport_Media_ID
ORDER BY V.Suport_Media_ID ASC;
```

The schema is located at:
https://imageshack.com/i/hl0DNwc1p

Comment: There's no `Support_Media` table in your join, you can't use `Support_Media.Support_Media_ID`.

Comment: Should the `DVD D1` join actually be `Support_Media`?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want, but I suspect you need a `UNION` to combine the `DVD` and `VHS` tables, not a `JOIN`.

Comment: Yes. But I've read that union doesn't work on tables but on result sets.

Comment: Put the `UNION` in a subquery, and `JOIN` with that.

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: In a view, you can't put a subquery in a FROM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `DVD` and `VHS` separately with the other tables, and then combine them with `UNION`

```
CREATE VIEW Informatii_Suport_Media AS
SELECT Titlu, Actori_Principali, Tip, Durata_Film, Data_Lansare, Pret
FROM DVD D
INNER JOIN Support_Media S ON S.Suport_Media_ID = D.Suport_Media_ID
INNER JOIN Film F ON F.Film_ID = D.Film_ID
GROUP BY S.Suport_Media_ID
UNION
SELECT Titlu, Actori_Principali, Tip, Durata_Film, Data_Lansare, Pret
FROM VHS V
INNER JOIN Support_Media S ON S.Suport_Media_ID = V.Suport_Media_ID
INNER JOIN Film F ON F.Film_ID = V.Film_ID
GROUP BY S.Suport_Media_ID
```

Another way to get around the restriction against putting a subquery in the `FROM` clause of a view is by creating another view:

```
CREATE VIEW DVD_VHS AS
SELECT Support_Media_ID, Film_ID
FROM DVD
UNION
SELECT Support_Media_ID, Film_ID
FROM VHS;

CREATE VIEW Informatii_Suport_Media AS
SELECT Titlu, Actori_Principali, Tip, Durata_Film, Data_Lansare, Pret
FROM DVD_VHS DV
INNER JOIN Support_Media S ON S.Suport_Media_ID = DV.Suport_Media_ID
INNER JOIN Film F ON F.Film_ID = DV.Film_ID
GROUP BY S.Suport_Media_ID
ORDER BY S.Support_Media_ID ASC
```